# How can I debug a funcargs function?

Tags: pytest

How can I drop into pdb inside a funcargs function? And how can I see output from print statements in funcargs functions?

---

My original question included the following, but it turns out I was simply instrumenting the wrong funcarg. Sigh.

> I tried:
>
> ```
> print "hi from inside funcargs"
> ```
>
> invoking with and without -s.
>
> I tried:
>
> ```
> import pytest
> pytest.set_trace()
> ```
>
> And:
>
> ```
> import pdb
> pdb.set_trace()
> ```
>
> And:
>
> ```
> raise "hi from inside funcargs"
> ```
>
> None produced any output or caused a test failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug a funcarg:

```
def pytest_funcarg__myfuncarg(request):
    import pytest
    pytest.set_trace()
    ...

def test_function(myfuncarg):
    ...
```

Then:

```
python -m pytest test_function.py
```

As [Ronny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78110/ronny) answered, to see output from a funcarg, `pytest -s` works.

Answer (score 2):

first thing that comes to mind is py.test -s

but by default funcargs give you tracebacks and output/error - what plugins are you using? something is clearly hiding it

for example for the program

```
def pytest_funcarg__foo(request):
    print 'hi'
    raise IOError

def test_fun(foo):
   pass
```

a py.test call gives me both - a traceback in the funcarg function and text